# Parsing and plotting in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to write code to parse a long output file. I have these geometry steps and each geometry step has data about Total Energy and Force Component. I am trying to create a Python code to extract this data and plot it. But I am having trouble with the code. Here's a sample of what the file looks like:

```
********************************************************************************
** Geometry step: 2
********************************************************************************

  iSCC Total electronic   Diff electronic      SCC error    
    1   -0.13140455E+03    0.00000000E+00    0.80416267E-02
    2   -0.13140455E+03   -0.41687170E-06    0.78970859E-02
    3   -0.13140456E+03   -0.97828672E-05    0.12929848E-02
    4   -0.13140456E+03   -0.42484487E-08    0.12745147E-02
    5   -0.13140456E+03   -0.12460347E-06    0.16447666E-03
    6   -0.13140456E+03   -0.28137492E-09    0.16240624E-03
    7   -0.13140456E+03   -0.73972046E-08    0.47666031E-04
    8   -0.13140456E+03   -0.71906925E-11    0.47054893E-04
    9   -0.13140456E+03   -0.26108182E-09    0.75455588E-05

 Total Energy:                    -129.5264160339 H
 Total Mermin free energy:        -129.5264160339 H
 Maximal force component:            0.692168E-01
>> Charges saved for restart in charges.bin

********************************************************************************
** Geometry step: 3
********************************************************************************

  iSCC Total electronic   Diff electronic      SCC error    
    1   -0.13142408E+03    0.00000000E+00    0.70873553E-01
    2   -0.13142412E+03   -0.42398687E-04    0.69196487E-01
    3   -0.13142507E+03   -0.95071621E-03    0.17135484E-01
    4   -0.13142508E+03   -0.18235795E-05    0.16803807E-01
    5   -0.13142510E+03   -0.25629573E-04    0.29259529E-02
    6   -0.13142510E+03    0.83017852E-07    0.28212127E-02
    7   -0.13142510E+03   -0.13392216E-05    0.66787494E-03
    8   -0.13142510E+03   -0.10173551E-08    0.66443460E-03
    9   -0.13142510E+03   -0.65849093E-07    0.12132063E-03
   10   -0.13142510E+03   -0.35652192E-09    0.11137555E-03
   11   -0.13142510E+03   -0.17755042E-08    0.16200251E-04
   12   -0.13142510E+03   -0.53717031E-11    0.15003954E-04
   13   -0.13142510E+03   -0.25210056E-10    0.52148196E-05

 Total Energy:                    -129.5502305350 H
 Total Mermin free energy:        -129.5502305350 H
 Maximal force component:            0.647219E-01
>> Charges saved for restart in charges.bin
```

EDIT: Here's the code I have so far. I can find the values for Total Energy and Force but I don't understand how to save them into a separate list.

```
import csv

stepsize = 0
data = {}
with open('/Users/ykathur2/Desktop/glu18_job.out', 'r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:
        if line.startswith("Total Energy"):
```

Comment: "I am having trouble with the code" - We're going to need to see the code you've tried and exactly what trouble you're having.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 'simple to read' parser for your data. It builds an OrderedDict that has the steps as key and a list with your data as value. I hope it will be helpful to understand how to approach simple parsing.

```
text = \
'''
********************************************************************************
** Geometry step: 2
********************************************************************************

  iSCC Total electronic   Diff electronic      SCC error    
    1   -0.13140455E+03    0.00000000E+00    0.80416267E-02
    2   -0.13140455E+03   -0.41687170E-06    0.78970859E-02
    3   -0.13140456E+03   -0.97828672E-05    0.12929848E-02
    4   -0.13140456E+03   -0.42484487E-08    0.12745147E-02
    5   -0.13140456E+03   -0.12460347E-06    0.16447666E-03
    6   -0.13140456E+03   -0.28137492E-09    0.16240624E-03
    7   -0.13140456E+03   -0.73972046E-08    0.47666031E-04
    8   -0.13140456E+03   -0.71906925E-11    0.47054893E-04
    9   -0.13140456E+03   -0.26108182E-09    0.75455588E-05

 Total Energy:                    -129.5264160339 H
 Total Mermin free energy:        -129.5264160339 H
 Maximal force component:            0.692168E-01
>> Charges saved for restart in charges.bin

********************************************************************************
** Geometry step: 3
********************************************************************************

  iSCC Total electronic   Diff electronic      SCC error    
    1   -0.13142408E+03    0.00000000E+00    0.70873553E-01
    2   -0.13142412E+03   -0.42398687E-04    0.69196487E-01
    3   -0.13142507E+03   -0.95071621E-03    0.17135484E-01
    4   -0.13142508E+03   -0.18235795E-05    0.16803807E-01
    5   -0.13142510E+03   -0.25629573E-04    0.29259529E-02
    6   -0.13142510E+03    0.83017852E-07    0.28212127E-02
    7   -0.13142510E+03   -0.13392216E-05    0.66787494E-03
    8   -0.13142510E+03   -0.10173551E-08    0.66443460E-03
    9   -0.13142510E+03   -0.65849093E-07    0.12132063E-03
   10   -0.13142510E+03   -0.35652192E-09    0.11137555E-03
   11   -0.13142510E+03   -0.17755042E-08    0.16200251E-04
   12   -0.13142510E+03   -0.53717031E-11    0.15003954E-04
   13   -0.13142510E+03   -0.25210056E-10    0.52148196E-05

 Total Energy:                    -129.5502305350 H
 Total Mermin free energy:        -129.5502305350 H
 Maximal force component:            0.647219E-01
>> Charges saved for restart in charges.bin
'''

from collections import OrderedDict
data = OrderedDict()
for line in text.split('\n'):
    if 'step:' in line:
        step = line.split('step:')[1].strip()
        data[step] = []

    if 'iSCC' in line:
        header = line.split()
        data[step].append(header)

    if line.startswith('   '): #data array
        data[step].append(line.split())

    if 'Total Energy:' in line:
        data[step].append(line.split('Total Energy:')[1].strip())

    if 'Total Mermin free energy:' in line:
        data[step].append(line.split('Total Mermin free energy:')[1].strip())

    if 'Maximal force component:' in line:
        data[step].append(line.split('Maximal force component:')[1].strip())
```

If now you look at 'data'...

```
data

OrderedDict([('2',
              [['iSCC',
                'Total',
                'electronic',
                'Diff',
                'electronic',
                'SCC',
                'error'],
               ['1', '-0.13140455E+03', '0.00000000E+00', '0.80416267E-02'],
               ['2', '-0.13140455E+03', '-0.41687170E-06', '0.78970859E-02'],
               ['3', '-0.13140456E+03', '-0.97828672E-05', '0.12929848E-02'],
               ['4', '-0.13140456E+03', '-0.42484487E-08', '0.12745147E-02'],
               ['5', '-0.13140456E+03', '-0.12460347E-06', '0.16447666E-03'],
               ['6', '-0.13140456E+03', '-0.28137492E-09', '0.16240624E-03'],
               ['7', '-0.13140456E+03', '-0.73972046E-08', '0.47666031E-04'],
               ['8', '-0.13140456E+03', '-0.71906925E-11', '0.47054893E-04'],
               ['9', '-0.13140456E+03', '-0.26108182E-09', '0.75455588E-05'],
               '-129.5264160339 H',
               '-129.5264160339 H',
               '0.692168E-01']),
             ('3',
              [['iSCC',
                'Total',
                'electronic',
                'Diff',
                'electronic',
                'SCC',
                'error'],
               ['1', '-0.13142408E+03', '0.00000000E+00', '0.70873553E-01'],
               ['2', '-0.13142412E+03', '-0.42398687E-04', '0.69196487E-01'],
               ['3', '-0.13142507E+03', '-0.95071621E-03', '0.17135484E-01'],
               ['4', '-0.13142508E+03', '-0.18235795E-05', '0.16803807E-01'],
               ['5', '-0.13142510E+03', '-0.25629573E-04', '0.29259529E-02'],
               ['6', '-0.13142510E+03', '0.83017852E-07', '0.28212127E-02'],
               ['7', '-0.13142510E+03', '-0.13392216E-05', '0.66787494E-03'],
               ['8', '-0.13142510E+03', '-0.10173551E-08', '0.66443460E-03'],
               ['9', '-0.13142510E+03', '-0.65849093E-07', '0.12132063E-03'],
               ['10', '-0.13142510E+03', '-0.35652192E-09', '0.11137555E-03'],
               ['11', '-0.13142510E+03', '-0.17755042E-08', '0.16200251E-04'],
               ['12', '-0.13142510E+03', '-0.53717031E-11', '0.15003954E-04'],
               ['13', '-0.13142510E+03', '-0.25210056E-10', '0.52148196E-05'],
               '-129.5502305350 H',
               '-129.5502305350 H',
               '0.647219E-01'])])
```

... you get all well organised.

About the plotting... what do you need to plot exactly?
There is no fast answer for that, but matplotlib should be good to start...

UPDATE about data selection and plotting.

Here is the a version of the code to select only 'Total Energy' and 'Maximal force component'.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

data = OrderedDict()
for line in text.split('\n'):
    if 'step:' in line:
        step = line.split('step:')[1].strip()
        data[step] = []

    if 'Total Energy:' in line:
        data[step].append(float(line.split('Total Energy:')[1].replace('H','').strip()))

    if 'Maximal force component:' in line:
        data[step].append(float(line.split('Maximal force component:')[1].strip()))
```

and here is the plotting part...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pet

x = []
y = []
for step in data:
    x.append(data[step][0])#all 'Total Energy'
    y.append(data[step][1])#all 'Maximal force component'
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: So, I don't really need the coordinates associated with each step size, all I need is the value for total energy and force and I have 20000 steps. So, I want to create a list of these two values and subsequently plot them. I wrote a few lines of code that help me convert every line and save each line as a string.

Comment: Thank you! I worked it out with your help and struggling with it.